# Embedded Case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query (which works) however, I want to be able to make it so I don't need to rerun the query to change the date ranges.

What I have here is it is pulling customer name and the amount and summing it. I need it broken down monthly by fiscal year, so what I would just do is change the year and rerun it, but I want to make the query more efficient so it doesn't need to be changed in the future (except the end date for a new FY) So after it takes the sum of each month (July to June), I want it to show the FY. So the date ranges from 2014 to 2015 should show a column called FY and have 2015 in the column. I am pretty certain I am on the right track but not there. I only showed what I was working on for the first case (which will be replicated for the other cases)

Could this just be an IF statement loop instead of another case statement? Any help with direction would be great to help me learn. I got this far, but just want to make the code more efficient for someone to use

```
Declare @StartDate datetime
Declare @EndDate datetime
set @StartDate = convert(datetime, '07/01/2014')
set @EndDate = convert(datetime, '06/30/2017')

select
d.CUSTNMBR Customer_ID,
d.CUSTNAME Customer_Name,
'A' as Company,
sum(case when month(d.DOCDATE) = 7
  then d.SALES else 0 end) July,
    case when datetime between '07/01/2016' and '06/30/2017' as '2017'
         when datetime between '07/01/2015' and '06/30/2016' as '2016'
         when datetime between '07/01/2014' and '06/30/2015' as '2015'
    END
sum(case when month(d.DOCDATE) = 8
  then d.SALES else 0 end) August,
sum(case when month(d.DOCDATE) = 9
  then d.SALES else 0 end) September,
sum(case when month(d.DOCDATE) = 10
  then d.SALES else 0 end) October,
sum(case when month(d.DOCDATE) = 11
  then d.SALES else 0 end) November,
sum(case when month(d.DOCDATE) = 12
  then d.SALES else 0 end) December,
sum(case when month(d.DOCDATE) = 1
  then d.SALES else 0 end) January,
sum(case when month(d.DOCDATE) = 2
  then d.SALES else 0 end) February,
sum(case when month(d.DOCDATE) = 3
  then d.SALES else 0 end) March,
sum(case when month(d.DOCDATE) = 4
  then d.SALES else 0 end) April,
sum(case when month(d.DOCDATE) = 5
  then d.SALES else 0 end) May,
sum(case when month(d.DOCDATE) = 6
  then d.SALES else 0 end) June,
sum(d.SALES) 'Year to Date'

from
(select s.DOCDATE, s.CUSTNMBR, c.CUSTNAME,
 case s.SOPTYPE
   when 3 then s.DOCAMNT
   when 4 then s.DOCAMNT*-1
   end SALES
 from a1.dbo.S200 s
 left outer join a1.dbo.RM1 c
   on s.CUSTNMBR = c.CUSTNMBR
 where s.VOIDSTTS = 0
   and s.SOPTYPE in (3,4) and 
   s.DOCDATE between @StartDate and @EndDate -- Fiscal Year
 ) d

group by d.CUSTNMBR, d.CUSTNAME
```

Comment: `case when datetime between '07/01/2016' and '06/30/2017' as '2017'
         when datetime between '07/01/2015' and '06/30/2016' as '2016'
         when datetime between '07/01/2014' and '06/30/2015' as '2015'
    END` wrong syntax, correct it.

Comment: Also, your current query aggregates all months across every year during startDate - endDate range. No conditionals are made by year. So August column would be Aug 2014 + Aug 2015 + Aug 2016.

Comment: Would it just make sense to do one year at a time? That's the way I have it set up currently for the two historical fiscal years and the current year is separate. I was shooting for a way to combine all 3 years (into one query but keeping the months separate) so when I'm in excel, it is all one query and in one table to make manipulating the data easier.

Comment: Look into pivot if you want to shorten this a little although I think your picture of "efficient" is inaccurate. You won't be able to change the alias of the year column without dynamic sql though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a recursive CTE that iterates through each fiscal year and then run a `CROSS JOIN...WHERE` (`CROSS APPLY` can work too) on your existing derived table. The `WHERE` conditions `DOCDate` to fiscal year start and end ranges. And going forward, simply change the declaration lines for each fiscal year. In fact, you can set up `@end INT = 2020` to anticipate future data!

```
DECLARE @start INT = 2014;
DECLARE @end INT = 2016;

WITH fiscalyears AS (
    SELECT @start + 1 AS FY, 
           CONVERT(datetime, cast(1 as varchar)+'/'+cast(7 as varchar)+'/'+cast(@start as varchar), 103) As StartRng,
           CONVERT(datetime, cast(30 as varchar)+'/'+cast(6 as varchar)+'/'+cast(@start + 1 as varchar), 103) As EndRng
    UNION ALL
    SELECT FY + 1, 
           CONVERT(datetime, cast(1 as varchar)+'/'+cast(7 as varchar)+'/'+cast(FY + 1 as varchar), 103),
           CONVERT(datetime, cast(30 as varchar)+'/'+cast(6 as varchar)+'/'+cast(FY + 2 as varchar), 103) 
    FROM  fiscalyears
    WHERE FY < @end
)

-- FY     StartRng                  EndRng
-- 2015   2014-07-01 00:00:00.000   2015-06-30 00:00:00.000
-- 2016   2015-07-01 00:00:00.000   2016-06-30 00:00:00.000
---2017   2016-07-01 00:00:00.000   2017-06-30 00:00:00.000

select
     d.CUSTNMBR Customer_ID,
     d.CUSTNAME Customer_Name,
     'A' as Company,
     d.FY As FY,
     sum(case when month(d.DOCDATE) = 7 then d.SALES else 0 end) AS July,    
     sum(case when month(d.DOCDATE) = 8 then d.SALES else 0 end) AS August,
     sum(case when month(d.DOCDATE) = 9 then d.SALES else 0 end) AS September,
     sum(case when month(d.DOCDATE) = 10 then d.SALES else 0 end) AS October,
     sum(case when month(d.DOCDATE) = 11 then d.SALES else 0 end) AS November,
     sum(case when month(d.DOCDATE) = 12 then d.SALES else 0 end) AS December,
     sum(case when month(d.DOCDATE) = 1 then d.SALES else 0 end) AS January,
     sum(case when month(d.DOCDATE) = 2 then d.SALES else 0 end) AS February,
     sum(case when month(d.DOCDATE) = 3 then d.SALES else 0 end) AS March,
     sum(case when month(d.DOCDATE) = 4 then d.SALES else 0 end) AS April,
     sum(case when month(d.DOCDATE) = 5 then d.SALES else 0 end) AS May,
     sum(case when month(d.DOCDATE) = 6 then d.SALES else 0 end) AS June,
     sum(d.SALES) 'Year to Date'

from
     (select f.FY, s.DOCDATE, s.CUSTNMBR, c.CUSTNAME,
             case s.SOPTYPE
                when 3 then s.DOCAMNT
                when 4 then s.DOCAMNT*-1
             end SALES
     from a1.dbo.S200 s
     left outer join a1.dbo.RM1 c
             on s.CUSTNMBR = c.CUSTNMBR
     cross join fiscalyears f  
     where s.VOIDSTTS = 0 
       and s.SOPTYPE in (3,4) 
       and s.DOCDATE between f.StartRng and f.EndRng) d

group by d.CUSTNMBR, 
         d.CUSTNAME, 
         d.FY
```

Comment: This worked, I had to make a few small modifications because we use 2005 sql server. Can you explain why/what reason you declared the year as an int but then converted it back to datetime? I appreciate the assistance on this. I learn a lot by doing the work, either right or needing assistance, but then reading the code and seeing the logic work in order to grasp concepts.

Comment: Awesome! The recursive CTE does both: retains the year as int and creates the start and end datetime values iteratively. These datetime ranges are needed to run the `BETWEEN` comparison on the `DOCDate` (a datetime field).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to create functions?  If so, create a (re-usable) scalar function for FY.  E.g.:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FY (input_date as smalldatetime) 

RETURNS int

BEGIN

    DECLARE @return int
    SET @return = year(input_date)

    IF month(input_date) <= 6
        @return = @return + 1

    RETURN @return

END
```

Then Use the function in your SELECT...

```
SELECT
   ...,
   FY(d.DOCDATE),
   ...
FROM
   ...
```

Otherwise, you can inline the function -- e.g.:

```
SELECT
   ...,
   CASE WHEN Month(d.DOCDATE) <= 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + year(d.DOCDATE) as FY
   ...
```

Also worth mentioning -- it looks like you're naming your Months the hard way.

Try this instead:

```
DATENAME(month,d.DOCDATE),
```

Also...

Suggest keeping your query's data and layout separated a bit more (for example, where you're create a horizontal layout for your months) -- you might like what PIVOT (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) can do for you...

If you do this, you can keep your query's data a little cleaner -- and then use it's output in other queries as well.  More re-usability = less work for you!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am proposing that the S200 table shall have computed columns as helper like this:

```
create table S200 
(
    CUSTNMBR varchar(10) null,
    DOCDATE date null,
    SOPTYPE int null,
    DOCAMNT money null,
    FISCALYEAR as datepart(year, DOCDATE) + 
        case when datepart(month, DOCDATE) >= 7 then 1 else 0 end,
    FISCALMONTHNAME as (datename(month, DOCDATE))
)
```

Then we can simply `PIVOT` it like:

```
select
    *,
    isnull([January], 0) +  
    isnull([February], 0) + 
    isnull([March], 0) +
    isnull([April], 0) +
    isnull([May], 0) +
    isnull([June], 0) + 
    isnull([July], 0) +
    isnull([August], 0) + 
    isnull([September], 0) + 
    isnull([October], 0) +
    isnull([November], 0) + 
    isnull([December], 0) as YearToDate
from
(
    select
        s.CUSTNMBR,
        s.FISCALYEAR,
        FISCALMONTHNAME,
        case s.SOPTYPE
            when 3 then s.DOCAMNT
            when 4 then -s.DOCAMNT
            end as SALES
    from 
        S200 as s
)
as d
pivot
(
    sum
    (
        d.SALES
    )
    for d.FISCALMONTHNAME in 
    (
        [January], 
        [February], 
        [March], 
        [April], 
        [May], 
        [June], 
        [July], 
        [August], 
        [September], 
        [October], 
        [November], 
        [December]
    )
)
as p
order by 2, 1
```

If you have a [Tally](http://sql-question.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/what-is-tally-table-in-sql-server.html) table, you can mock populate S200 for 3 years starts from 2014 for 3 customers:

```
truncate table S200

insert 
    S200 
select 
    101 + cast(3 * rand(checksum(newid())) as int),
    dateadd(day, cast(3 * 365 * rand(checksum(newid())) as int),
        datefromparts(2014, 1, 1)),
    case when rand(checksum(newid())) > .6 then 4 else 3 end,
    1 + cast(100 * rand(checksum(newid())) as int)
from 
    Tally
where
    Id <= 1000
```

You may have result like this:

```
| CUSTNMBR | FISCALYEAR | January | February | March   | April  | May     | June    | July    | August  | September | October | November | December | YearToDate |
|----------|------------|---------|----------|---------|--------|---------|---------|---------|---------|-----------|---------|----------|----------|------------|
| 101      | 2014       | 160.00  | 143.00   | 139.00  | 28.00  | 247.00  | 28.00   | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      | NULL    | NULL     | NULL     | 745.00     |
| 102      | 2014       | 24.00   | 158.00   | -244.00 | -85.00 | 103.00  | 20.00   | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      | NULL    | NULL     | NULL     | -24.00     |
| 103      | 2014       | 123.00  | -167.00  | -6.00   | -30.00 | -53.00  | 15.00   | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      | NULL    | NULL     | NULL     | -118.00    |
| 101      | 2015       | 14.00   | 200.00   | 304.00  | 137.00 | 236.00  | -245.00 | 289.00  | 258.00  | 192.00    | -13.00  | 275.00   | 9.00     | 1656.00    |
| 102      | 2015       | -40.00  | 115.00   | -36.00  | 142.00 | -18.00  | 48.00   | -262.00 | -71.00  | 24.00     | 189.00  | -166.00  | -49.00   | -124.00    |
| 103      | 2015       | 265.00  | -103.00  | 73.00   | -50.00 | 61.00   | -268.00 | -20.00  | -214.00 | -21.00    | 50.00   | -48.00   | -204.00  | -479.00    |
| 101      | 2016       | 207.00  | -201.00  | 34.00   | 397.00 | -156.00 | 267.00  | -272.00 | -156.00 | -61.00    | -98.00  | 575.00   | 107.00   | 643.00     |
| 102      | 2016       | 27.00   | 20.00    | 199.00  | 328.00 | 44.00   | 55.00   | 447.00  | 188.00  | -57.00    | -118.00 | -1.00    | 74.00    | 1206.00    |
| 103      | 2016       | -114.00 | 333.00   | 299.00  | 145.00 | 80.00   | -8.00   | 58.00   | -151.00 | 44.00     | 799.00  | 218.00   | 14.00    | 1717.00    |
| 101      | 2017       | NULL    | NULL     | NULL    | NULL   | NULL    | NULL    | -154.00 | -56.00  | 192.00    | -283.00 | 371.00   | 155.00   | 225.00     |
| 102      | 2017       | NULL    | NULL     | NULL    | NULL   | NULL    | NULL    | 11.00   | -50.00  | 82.00     | 8.00    | 562.00   | -26.00   | 587.00     |
| 103      | 2017       | NULL    | NULL     | NULL    | NULL   | NULL    | NULL    | 294.00  | -93.00  | -51.00    | 29.00   | 322.00   | 392.00   | 893.00     |
```

Perhaps with certain indexes on those computed columns, it would give even better performance.